# Can rust library be used from another languages in a way c libraries do?

Tags: dll, rust, shared-libraries

Writing such library will I have to sacrifice std? How, for example, will do I write python bindings to rust library, if possible?

Comment: Short version: it's just as good as C, better in most places. The long version I am not well suited to writing, but I've pinged someone who's worked with Ruby/Rust interop (Yehuda Katz, for [Skylight](http://skylight.io).)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First, indicate to Rust that you want to create a function visible to C:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn some_func() { ... }
```

This tells Rust to avoid mangling the output symbol and to use the C ABI.

Next, you will need to use C-compatible types when crossing the boundary. Here is some advice that has worked for me:

- If you are planning to pass a Rust structure to C as opaque data, which it will pass back into other functions, return it as a `Box<T>`, and take it as a `&T` or `Box<T>`. Essentially, this means that you are giving up ownership of the structure in Rust, and giving ownership to the C code. The C code must ensure that if it passes the pointer back into a function that takes a Box, it **no longer uses it**.
- If you are planning to pass a Rust structure to C as a C structure, Rust conveniently represents its structs in a C-compatible way. However, you will want to restrict the kinds of values you put in these structs to types that also have compatible C representations. Numeric types and booleans are safe, of course.
- You can see the Rust representation of more complex types (like vecs and strings) in the docs under [core::raw](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/raw/index.html). A `&str` and `&[T]` are represented as [raw::Slice](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/raw/struct.Slice.html) while a `Vec<T>` is represented as a [raw::Vec](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/raw/struct.Vec.html).
- You can also convert types into the [libc::types](http://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/)
- Finally, you may find yourself needing to work with pointers directly. Check out [std::mem](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/index.html) for useful APIs.

Comment: While structs are currently C-compatible in layout, they will not be for much longer, by default; [an RFC was just accepted which will change the layout to undefined unless you use `#[repr(C)]` on the struct](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/0fc8bc0a2d098dc6f007e53f5da20cf11934a297/active/0018-undefined-struct-layout.md).

Comment: Isn't `core::raw::Vec<T>` the representation for an old-style `~[T]` vector? I think `Vec<T>` proper now has a different representation (`{length,capacity,pointer-to-array-of-T}` instead of `pointer-to-{length,capacity,array-of-capacity-Ts}`).

Comment: Could you give example code? I'm not sure I follow. I write library in Rust, make some functions "C"-like, and those functions later can be used to, say, making python bindings, because from python point of view this functions are indistinguishable from ordinary C functions, correct?

Comment: So it is safe to have a `pub extern` function that returns a `Box<T>` and then receive the same value from C code as `&T`/`&mut T`? Doesn't require conversion? (Makes sense if the internal representation of a `Box<T>` *really is* a zero cost abstraction). I guess I'll just try it and see.